# plausible science for why an enzyme breaks down a substrate better at 4 degrees rather than 20 degrees

Tags: biochemistry, lab-techniques, enzymes, experiment

An enzyme was found to have an optimal temperature of 20 degrees. The same enzyme in sheep liver extract was found to have an optimal temperature of 4 degrees. What are some of the factors that can contribute to the differences observed?

Comment: What enzyme? What substract? Who defined its optimal temperature? Who collected the data? How was the experiment conducted? As you can see, a lot of questions must be addressed for anyone be able to write an answer.

Comment: I can think of examples in living cells where the apparent optimal temperature for the activity of certain biochemical processes change in different chemical environments. But, I've never really thought about this occurring in extracts/purified enzymes. I agree with @tomd, this should not be closed.

Comment: Seems like this question does have a pretty simple answer, i.e. that [chemical kinetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_kinetics) can vary with the solution, whether through biologically explicit mechanisms like enzyme inhibitors/activators or through more mundane mechanisms like the solution's ionic strength.  So, the performance of an enzyme'll vary with its environment, so that an enzyme was found to behave differently in two different environments is a really unsurprising result.

Comment: Then, when the question asks, "_What are some of the factors that can contribute to the differences observed?_", the answer's basically that stuff: inhibitors/activators, ionic strength, relative concentrations of reactants, possible denaturation during extraction, etc..  Additionally, these factors can act on not just the enzyme itself, but also the substrate(s).

Comment: __*tl;dr*-__  This question can probably be re-opened, as it has a pretty simple answer.